# Rails multiple belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a schema as in the figure attached [image: schema]

now in answer module i have following code

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: "project_id"
    belongs_to :questionair, class_name: "Questionair", foreign_key: "questionair_id"
end
```

are these belong_to lines correct? when i delete project, answer gets deleted as intended but in case of questionnaire it fails to delete associated answer row.
what must i do extra .I have:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
class Questionair < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :questionair
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end

class Questionair < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

To delete record in association you have to use

```
project.destroy
```

if you use

```
project.delete #this does not trigger dependent destroy
```

Comment: yo man.. I triggered delete and hoped to work with .destroy, i messed up with .delete and .destroy, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

How I can understand you, you just want to destroy all dependencies in single command:

```
project.destroy 
# delete all nested answers, 
# questionairies and questionairies->answers
```

So you need add one line to your Project model.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questionairies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

instead of

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If I understand your incorrect, please, explain your question more deeply.